# Create Table from Select with rows as Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a table with columns based on my paramaters. The parameter is string variable and it consists of month and year combinations of multiple values seperated by comma. Based on this values i need to create temp table. I tried like below

```
DECLARE @compareMonths VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @compareCount INT
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @compareMonths = '2014-01,2014-02'

select @cols =  STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
 CONVERT(CHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, CAST(
      CAST(SUBSTRING(Data, 0, 5) AS VARCHAR(4)) +
      RIGHT('0' + CAST(SUBSTRING(Data, 6, 2) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
      RIGHT('0' + CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) 
   AS DATETIME))) + ' ' + CAST(SUBSTRING(Data, 0, 5) AS VARCHAR(4))
                      FROM dbo.Split(@compareMonths, ',')
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');
```

Here i got the column name as monthname and year but how to create table dynamically based on this. I don't have any value column to use pivot.

My outout table must have 2 columns named Jan 2014, Feb 2014

Comment: You need to be clear about what you want to do. You want to extract all the words in a csv string and then insert them all into the same column ? Also, what is the problem you are facing ? Is it an error ? Sample table ?

Comment: I splitted and got as table which contains the the values as rows. Now i need to create temp table from these rows. I dont know how to create table by transposing the rows to columns. I don't have other value columns to use pivot also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to a SQL database table, you can [build Dynamic SQL script](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/build-sql-server-dynamic-sql-query-example.aspx) which forms a CREATE TABLE script as follows

```
DECLARE @compareMonths VARCHAR(2000)
SET @compareMonths = '2014-01,2014-02'

declare @sql nvarchar(max) 

SELECT @sql = isnull(@sql + ',','') + ( '[' + val + ']') + ' varchar(100)' from dbo.Split(@compareMonths, ',')

SET @sql = N'CREATE Table OutputTable (' + @sql + ')'
exec sp_executeSql @sql

select * from OutputTable
```

In above script, I also used a [sql string split function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx) where you can find the source codes at the referenced tutorial

At the end you will have a table named OutputTable in your database with two columns

Comment: Thanks. I used this way and update my logic change as month and year